# Advertencia: argumento no válido proporcionado para foreach ()

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

Estoy en un proyecto en laravel y soy nuevo, estoy tratando de hacer un sistema de notas y quiero que cada maestro pueda ver los alumnos que tiene matriculado en su clase, hice las consultas y corrobore que las consultas estuvieran buenas y me funcionan, pero en el foreach() me tira un error no deja pasar el arreglo

[image]

Estas son mis tablas de la base de datos, quiero mostrar el idAlumno de la tabla matricula cuando el idDocente de la tabla seccion es igual al idDocente de la tabla usuarios

```js
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Admin\Notas;
use App\Models\Admin\Matricula;
use App\Models\Admin\Seccion;

class NotasController extends Controller

{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        
        $matricula = Matricula::join('seccion','matricula.idSeccion','=','seccion.idSeccion')
                            ->where('seccion.idDocente','=',auth()->user()->idDocente)
                            ->orderBy('idAlumno')
                            ->get();
                  
        return view('admin\notas\index', compact('notas'))->with('notas');
    }
```

Estes es mi index del controllador

```js
@extends("theme.$theme.layout")
@section('titulo')
    Notas
@endsection

@section("scripts")
<script src="{{asset("assets/pages/scripts/admin/index.js")}}" type="text/javascript"></script>    
@endsection

@section('contenido')
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        @include('includes/mensaje')
        <div class="box box-primary">
                <div class="box-header with-border">
              <h3 class="box-title">Notas</h3>



              <div class="box-body table-responsive no-padding">
                <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>

                            <th>Nombre</th>
                            <th>Nota</th>
                            <th>Acción</th>
                            
                        </tr>

                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        if(is_array($matricula)|| is_object($matricula)){
                        
                           @foreach($matricula ?? ''  as $notas) 
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{$notas->idAlumno}}</td>
                                
                           
                            <td>{{$notas->idAlumno}}</td>
                          
                        <td>
                            <a href="{{route('editar_grado', ['idGrado' => $matricula ?? '' ?? ''->idMatricula])}}" class="btn-accion-tabla tooltipsC" title="Editar este registro">
                                <i class="fa fa-fw fa-pencil"></i>
                            </a>
                        </td>
                            </tr>
                           @endforeach
                        } else {
                            echo "Unfortunately, an error occured.";

                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>

            </div>



            </div>
            <div class="box-body table-responsive no-padding">
                

            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
@endsection
```

Este es mi vista

Comment: pues si le quito ?? ' ' eso me tira error y me dice que tengo que agregarlo

Comment: $matricula is undefined eso me dice

Comment: Make the variable optional in the blade template. Replace {{ $matricula }} with {{ $matricula ?? '' }}   pense que agregando corregiria el error

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, eso era el problema, ya funciona correctamente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para pasar datos a la vista no debes usar mas de un método, es decir si vas a trabajar con `with` basta con tenerlo así:

```
->with(["notas" => $notas]);
```

- Donde como notas hicimos uso de un *vector asociativo* para que posteriormente en la vista recuperes e iteres los datos en el `foreach` por medio de dicha clave.

Por otro lado si lo que vas a usar es el método `compact` propio de PHP, lo puedes hacer:

- Pasando la clave como texto, es decir entre comillas
- Debería funcionarte (aunque nunca lo he hecho) pasando la misma variable por su nombre como argumento de dicho método

Es decir:

```
compact($notas));

compact('notas'));
```

Comment: gracias, me ayudaste demasiado